# Storing a function in a hashmap

Tags: rust

I want to store a function inside a Hashmap in rust, but i dont know how to "get" it and call it at another location.
Here's what ive tried

```
type Ihello = fn() -> String;


fn main() {
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    let mut mapp: HashMap<String, Ihello> = HashMap::new();
    mapp.insert(
        "hello".to_string(),
        hello
    );
    let hello_string = "hello".to_string();
    let hello: Option<&Ihello> = book_reviews.get(&hello_string);
    
}

fn hello() -> String {
    String::from("HELLOHELLOHELLO")
}
```

I want to "call" the hello function later on, is there any way to do it?
or is there a alterative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Box` to store a reference to the function, then call the function that the `map.get(...).unwrap()` returns (notice we have `()()` on the last line).

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

type Ihello = dyn Fn() -> String;

fn hello() -> String {
    "HELLO".to_string()
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, Box<Ihello>> = HashMap::new();
    
    map.insert("hello", Box::new(hello));
    
    println!("{}", map.get("hello").unwrap()());
}
```

Comment: Boxing the Fn trait will help store closures in the HashMap (in addition to ordinary functions), but since that is not the asker's problem it seems a distraction here.

Comment: @hkBst Agreed, but it is worth noting that `fn() -> String` will only support functions while something like `Box<dyn FnMut() -> String>` also supports closures. In fact, IMHO the latter is more fitting here.

Answer (score 2):

[`HashMap.get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns [`Option<&Ihello>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) which means that the result could be either [`Some` value `Ihello`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#variant.Some) or [`None`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#variant.None)(If the key does not exists). So one solution is to destructure the `Option` using [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html#if-let) statement.

```
let hello: Option<&Ihello> = mapp.get(&hello_string);
if let Some(val) = hello {
    println!("{}", val()); // calling the function here
} else {
    println!("Key is missing!");
}
```